# Why does the NSSession dataTaskWithRequest completion handler use an implicitly unwrapped optional for the error parameter?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift, and I came across something that is confusing to me.  According to [the documentation for NSSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:), the dataTaskWithRequest method signature is as follows:

```
func dataTaskWithRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest,
   completionHandler completionHandler: ((NSData!,
                              NSURLResponse!,
                              NSError!) -> Void)?) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```

My question is, why would the NSError parameter to the completionHandler be an implicitly unwrapped optional, when it is totally valid for that parameter to be nil?  I would have expected it to be declared as an NSError? optional.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many of these types of inconsistencies across the board in the iOS SDK at the moment.

It's in a state of flux currently during the transition to Swift.

Remember all of these API's were written in Objective C. 
There are many other examples I can think of, e.g. NSURL etc.

All of this stuff is getting better as the API's mature and refine, however the automatic conversion from ObjC to Swift has left some quirks like the above example you provided.

Apple are reviewing each class and making appropriate changes to modernise the API's, including a best practice approach to Optionals however they're aren't finished yet.

Comment: So, to summarize, this probably wasn't a "thought-through" decision made by the iOS SDK developers, but rather a result of blanket conversion of the Objective C APIs to Swift?

Comment: Precisely, they automated the API conversion, and, in instances where it may not have been automatically obvious what to do, using implicitly unwrapped optionals was the easy default. Just look at CellForRowAtIndexPath, it changed a few times during the API progression.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  One last thing:  would you agree that the proper way to declare a function parameter that can legitimately be passed as nil (as is NSError in this case) is to declare it as an optional?  (I'm mainly curious about this not to point out things wrong with the iOS SDK, but I'm trying to figure out how to propertly declare my own function parameters)

Comment: Absolutely. In Swift it simple must be optional, if it may be nil.